# How to update email for User access requests?

Tags: permissions, access, site-settings, notifications, requestaccessmail

I am a new owner of a SharePoint site, and am trying to set it up so that I receive an email whenever a user requests access. I have gone into Site Settings -> Site Permissions -> Access Request Settings (on the Permission Tab) and put in my email in the dialog window. Even after doing this though I am still not receiving emails when a user requests access.

The only potential issue I can think of is that I am not the original owner of the SharePoint site, and the previous owner had his email set up to receive notifications when a user requested access. We have since gone in and deleted his email and put mine in instead, but the issue persists.

Does anyone know what I can do to make sure that I receive email notifications for when a user requests access? Otherwise I will have multiple requests aging while I am unaware.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: what is your permission level? how many email address on the Acess requests settings?

Comment: I have Full Control for the Site Collection, so it's my understanding that I should be able to edit the email address on the Access Request Setting. And now it is just one email address (mine). We had tried to have it be both mine and the previous owner, but we still ran into the same issue of me not receiving any email notifications.

Comment: is any body getting the emails, when you add both account or if it is just your email address?

Comment: When both of our emails were listed then the original owner continued to get emails. Now that it is just my email, the original owner no longer receives emails.

Comment: Add yourself into site collection admin group then try again....site setting> permission check site collection administrator

Comment: When I go into Site Setting -> the only options I have under Users and Permissions are "People and groups", "Site permissions", "Access requests and invitations", and "Site app permissions". Is the "Permission Check Site Collection Administrator" option under another group on the Site Settings page?

Comment: ask the site collection administrator to add you as a site collection admin.

Comment: basic question, do you have email associated with your id? if you setup alert on any list or document library, are you getting the email?

Comment: Ok I'll try that, I'm not aware of who our site collection administrator is, but my guess is that I will not be allowed to be added as a site collection admin - is there another way for me to receive these email notifications? 

And I set up an alert on a document, but I am not receiving any email notifications for the document.

Comment: looks like problem with your id, becuase if you are not getting the alerts thats mean there is no email address associated with it? are you on prem or office 365?

Comment: Hmm ok, I'm not sure why there'd be an issue with my ID, but I understand why we can conclude that could be an issue. We are on office 365

Comment: How could I go about checking to see if there is an email associated with my ID? Or checking to see if the email was entered incorrectly?